# compiling package with Rcpp outside of R-Studio in Windows

Tags: r, rcpp

I've successfully build my own package with Rcpp in R-Studio. However, when building the package in the Windows console, there are some error messages complaining file missing of `R.h`.

I set the `path` and `R_Home` environments with

```
SET PATH=D:\RTools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;D:\R3\bin;D:\RTools\bin;
SET R_HOME=D:\R3\
```

And the build command is

```
R CMD INSTALL  --byte-compile --build mypkg
```

Below are the compiling error messages:

```
g++ -m32 -I"/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"D:/R3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:
/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c Rcpp
Exports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from D:/R3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:0,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
D:/R3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:35:15: fatal error: R.h: No su
ch file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: After  some trying, I now can confirm that `R CMD INSTALL` doesn't recognize `${R_HOME}` in the `Makevars.win` file. That is why we see `-I"/include"` from the prompt. The content of `Makevars.win` is default as generated from Rcpp, that is: `PKG_LIBS = $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()")`

Comment: It works for CRAN's windows builds, it works for R-Forge's windows builds, it works for win-builder, it works for many (Windows) users on rcpp-devel.  Maybe you use a different shell.  Maybe your R CMD is non-standard.  With the few details you provided it is impossible to help you.

Comment: BTW you should not need to set `R_HOME` -- R tends to know where it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an include for `R.h`, as the error says.

And if you look at your compile line, the statement

```
 -I"/include"
```

is wrong relative to your stated `R_HOME` in `D:/R3`

You need to check your setup, somehow you confused R from using the correct include directory.
Rcpp builds just fine on Windows, you can even check by submitting your package to the [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) service.

Comment: Yes. The problem is how do I let R know where the correct `include` dir is. Do I miss other environment variables? I couldn't compile the Rcpp_hello_world package in dos either.